# how to make sqlite database query with some condtions

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

I have a reminder app where I want to show different schedules of programs. There I have four sections

1. Overview(details of all the schedules)
2. Today
3. Tomorrow
4. 10-days-later

   Now I can list 'overview' section with the help of cursoradapter. But I cannot list 'today' and rest of the sections--the screen remains blank. Here is my code of `todayActivity`

   in oncreate()---

   ```
       DatabaseHelper fdb = new DatabaseHelper(this);
       db = fdb.getReadableDatabase();
       cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from "+TABLE_NAME+" where "+COLUMN_DAY+" = "+day+" and "+
               COLUMN_MONTH+" = "+month+" and "+COLUMN_YEAR+" = "+year+";",null);

       adapter = new AppointmentAdapter(this, cursor);
       listView.setAdapter(adapter);
   ```

in onresume()----

```
        DatabaseHelper fdb = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        SQLiteDatabase db = fdb.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor newCursor = db.rawQuery("select * from "+TABLE_NAME+" where "+COLUMN_DAY+" = "+day+" and "+
                COLUMN_MONTH+" = "+month+" and "+COLUMN_YEAR+" = "+year+";",null);

        //RecyclerView recyclerView=findViewById(R.id.recycler);
        AppointmentAdapter adapter = (AppointmentAdapter)listView.getAdapter();

        adapter.changeCursor(newCursor);
        cursor = newCursor;
```

And this is bindView method in my custom cursor adapter class----

```
 public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

    int drawable = 0;
    ImageView imgView = view.findViewById(R.id.type_image);
    name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_NAME));
    type = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_TYPE));
    date = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_DAY));
    month = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_MONTH));
    year = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_YEAR));
    hour = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_HOUR));
    minute = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_MINUTE));
    phone = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_PHONE));

    if (type.equals("Health"))
        drawable = R.drawable.icons8_stethoscope_96;
    else if (type.equals("Personal"))
        drawable = R.drawable.icons8_resume_96;
    else if (type.equals("Work"))
        drawable = R.drawable.icons8_business_80;
    else if (type.equals("School"))
        drawable = R.drawable.icons8_school_80;
    else if (type.equals("Other"))
        drawable = R.drawable.icons8_exclamation_mark_48;

    imgView.setImageResource(drawable);

    TextView textView1 = view.findViewById(R.id.clock_text);
    textView1.setText(hour + ":" + minute);
    TextView textView2 = view.findViewById(R.id.date_text);
    textView2.setText(date + "-" + month + "-" + year);
    TextView textView = view.findViewById(R.id.nameText);
    textView.setText(name);
    TextView textView3 = view.findViewById(R.id.phoneText);
    textView3.setText(phone);
}
```

So, my question is how to make the cursor of custom cursoradapter know about the certain conditions from database that I need? This may be asked before, but I cannot find a solution for the problem. Please help me. Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try using db.query() which has selection and selectionArgs as parameter for conditional selection.

```
Cursor cursor = db.query(
    TABLE_NAME,   // The table to query
    projection,           // The array of columns to return (pass null to get all)
    selection,            // The columns for the WHERE clause
    selectionArgs,        // The values for the WHERE clause
    null,                 // don't group the rows
    null,                 // don't filter by row groups
    sortOrder             // The sort order
    );
```

in your case selction and selectionArgs will be :

```
 String selection = COLUMN_DAY+ " = ? AND"+COLUMN_MONTH+ " = ? 
 AND"+COLUMN_YEAR+" = ?";

 String[] selectionArgs = { day, month, year };
```

make sure day, month and year are strings.

Comment: same problem. Can you tell me where the change of new conditioned cursor is reflected in the custom cursor adapter class ?

Comment: day,month and year initialization as I have done---c = Calendar.getInstance();
        year = String.valueOf(c.get(Calendar.YEAR)); month = String.valueOf(c.get(Calendar.MONTH));
        day = String.valueOf(c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)); Is it right way?

Comment: I guess there wont be any change. check what value comes in your cursor. use `DatabaseUtils.dumpCursorToString(cursor)` it return string value that contains data in your cursor. print that string in log to check whether cursor has all values or filtered values or null.